# Боковая панель-меню в Linux

Tags: linux, gui

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать такую панель, как на скрине (слева): 
[image: Скриншот]

Если это какая-то отдельная утилита, то какая? 
Если это особенность конкретной графической среды или дистрибутива, то каких?

Comment: Cairo-Dock или что-нибудь типа того

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по скриншоту - это xfce. И подобная панель - стандартные возможности. Просто кликните по панели (либо если ее нет - запустите с консоли xfce4-panel) и выберите в меню "Panel->Panel Preferences". Там можно нажать плюсик и создать ещё одну панель. Также скорее всего выбрать mode: vertical/deskbar, снять галочку "Lock Panel" и ещё Length в до нужного размера. Потом можно взять слева или справа и перетащить в подходящее место.

А теперь можно просто добавить туда Launcher или что Вам нужно.